# Timetrex api JSON/SOAP login failed

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to use timetrex api, and for now I'm testing it using it's example in `/timetrex/api/soap/api_client_example.php`. but it returns "login failed" message although I'm using the correct username and password.
I checked the httpd error logs and it has the following message:

> PHP Notice:  SOAP Fault: (Code: HTTP, String: Could not connect to
>   host) - Request:  Response:  in
>   /var/www/html/timetrex/classes/modules/api/client/TimeTrexClientAPI.class.php
>   on line 157

Note that I'm using the following link to connect to the api:

```
http://192.168.x.x/timetrex/api/soap/api.php
```

How can I fine the problem and solve it?

Comment: https://192.168... it's an internal address, is it soppuse to be like that ?

Comment: yes I installed it in a local machine for testing purposes

Comment: sorry where i can find the code of /api/client/TimeTrexClientAPI.class.php  ?

Comment: it's actually locted in "timetrex/classes/modules/api/client/TimeTrexClientAPI.class.php", which is already included in the example code